# javascript sum array of arrays of objects together

Tags: javascript

i have an array with the following format

```
[
[{year:2015, value:23000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:1000, value1:2000},{year:2017,value:400, value1:3000}],
[{year:2015, value:10000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:2000, value1:3000},{year:2017,value:500, value1:2000}],
]
```

i want to sum them together, in this example, i want to have

```
[{year:2015,value:33000, value1:2000},{year:2016,value:3000, value1:5000},{year:2017,value:900, value1:5000}]
```

if there are only two arrays in the array but there maybe more arrays in the bigger array. how can i achieve this? currently, i am not able to figure out a good method. Thanks

Comment: Are there only two only two levels of arrays, or can inner arrays have arrays in them as well?

Comment: hi only two levels

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Ecmascript5* solution:

```js
var arr = [
        [{year:2015, value:23000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:1000, value1:2000},{year:2017,value:400, value1:3000}],
        [{year:2015, value:10000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:2000, value1:3000},{year:2017,value:500, value1:2000}]
    ],
    
    // summing up values for each `year`
    years = arr.reduce(function (r, a) {
        a.forEach(function (o) {
            y = o.year;
            if (Array.isArray(r[y])) {
                r[y][0] += o.value;
                r[y][1] += o.value1;
            } else {
                r[y] = [o.value, o.value1];
            }
        });
        return r;
    }, {}),

    // constructing the resulting array containing objects with `year` totals
    result = Object.keys(years).map(function (y) {
        return {year: y, value: years[y][0], value1: years[y][1]};
    });

console.log(result);
```

Comment: actually, there are more properties inside the objects, i tested in that case, this solution failed to work.[{year:2015, value:23000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:1000, value:200},{year:2017,value:400, value1:600}],

Comment: @onegun, you didn't mention that in your question and you didn't post the extended input array

Comment: yes, i was looking for a general solution, thought that cause the confusion, i will edit that

Comment: @onegun, even though you have changed your initial condition, I've updated my answer. See the update

Answer (score 1):

You can loop over the items and add value agains a year number (key) in a map / object.

```
var data = [
[{year:2015, value:23000},{year:2016,value:1000},{year:2017,value:400}],
[{year:2015, value:10000},{year:2016,value:2000},{year:2017,value:500}],
];

var output = {};

data.forEach(function(item) {
  item.forEach(function(obj) {
    output[obj.year] = (output[obj.year] || 0) + obj.value;
  });
});
output = [output]

console.log(output);
```

One way is to flat this 2D array first.

```
var output = {};
var flatArray = data.reduce(function(a, b) {
  return a.concat(b);
}, []);

flatArray.forEach(function(obj) {
  output[obj.year] = (output[obj.year] || 0) + obj.value;
});

output = [output]
console.log(output);
```

> output: [{
>     2015: 33000,
>     2016: 3000,
>     2017: 900
>   }]

Comment: Your output doesn't match his: `[{year:2015,value:33000},{year:2016,value:3000},{year:2017,value:900}]` where his is an array of objects and yours is an array of one object.

Comment: @ThisClark outer array does not make sense but I've update my code to match the exact same output.

Comment: actually, there are more properties inside the objects, i tested in that case, this solution failed to work.[{year:2015, value:23000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:1000, value:200},{year:2017,value:400, value1:600}], that is why i want that kind of output

Comment: @onegun An object can't have two keys with same name. `{year:2016,value:1000, value:200}` . Also you did not mentioned this in your question

Comment: hi i have updated the question, they are not same name properties, but one is value another is value1 used in the example

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hash table for collecting a single year and a nested approach for the arrays with iterating all properties of the given objects.

Then create new properties and add the actual value.

It works with an arbitrary count of properties.

```js
var data = [[{ year: 2015, value: 23000, value1: 1000 }, { year: 2016, value: 1000, value1: 2000 }, { year: 2017, value: 400, value1: 3000 }], [{ year: 2015, value: 10000, value1: 1000 }, { year: 2016, value: 2000, value1: 3000 }, { year: 2017, value: 500, value1: 2000 }]],
    result = data.reduce(function (hash) {
        return function (r, a) {
            a.forEach(function (o) {
                if (!hash[o.year]) {
                    hash[o.year] = { year: o.year };
                    r.push(hash[o.year]);
                }
                Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {
                    if (k !== 'year') {
                        hash[o.year][k] = (hash[o.year][k] || 0) + o[k];
                    }
                });
            });
            return r;
        };
    }(Object.create(null)), []);

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a working solution. This will do what you're looking for. Hope it helps!

```js
var arr =   [
      [{year:2015, value:23000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:1000, value1:2000},{year:2017,value:400, value1:3000}],
          [{year:2015, value:10000, value1:1000},{year:2016,value:2000, value1:3000},{year:2017,value:500, value1:2000}],
      ]

var result = [];

  for(var i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++){
      var count = 0
      var count2 = 0;
      for(var j = 0; j < arr.length; j++){
       var year = arr[j][i].year;
       count  += arr[j][i].value;
       count2 += arr[j][i].value1;
      }
      result.push({
          year: year,
          value: count,
          value1: count2
      });
  }
  console.log(result);
```